# MySQL If record in subquery AND 1 field not set or NOT in subquery at all

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm working through a process where I have to sync messages on multiple devices. If you read it or delete it on your phone, the next time you pick pick up your tablet, the message is marked as read or deleted there as well. Common and expected behavior.

Before the multiple device support, everything worked great. Now the problem is in the first subquery.

**Process:** If the message is read by a user, it gets logged by adding it to the log_table. If it gets deleted by a user, the deleted column in the log_table gets updated. If the message is UNREAD by that user it will not be in the log_table at all.

If there's an entry in the log_table for that user and that message, the query returns an empty result set. The problem is in the first subquery. If the message is read on one device there will be an entry in the log_table so NOT IN is producing a failure when the record has been read and this prohibits us from syncing that read message on the other device.

**NOTE:** Messages are not 1-to-1 but are 1-to-many.

**DESIRED RESULT:** 
What I need to do, is include the message if it's unread (not in log_table) OR if it's in log_table and NOT deleted.  Suggestions?

```
 SELECT A.*, T.name FROM a_table AS A 
 RIGHT JOIN types_table AS T ON A.msg_type = T.id 
 WHERE A.id NOT IN (SELECT msg_id AS id FROM log_table WHERE userid='3' AND msg_id = A.id AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(deleted) = 0) 
 AND 3 IN (SELECT userid FROM subscriber_table AS S WHERE S.userid='3') AND A.id > 01
```

Suggestions appreciated!

Comment: What is your question?  Sample data and desired results would definitely help other people understand what you might be trying to do.  Does your query not work?

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear but maybe not... I'm asking how to include records from a_table when no record exists in the log_table for that user OR a record exists in the log_table for that user but the record is not marked as deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is a conditional WHERE clause

```
 SELECT A.*, T.name FROM a_table AS A 
 RIGHT JOIN types_table AS T ON A.msg_type = T.id 
 WHERE A.id NOT IN (SELECT msg_id AS id FROM log_table WHERE (userid='3' AND msg_id = A.id AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(read) < 1) OR (userid='3' AND msg_id = A.id AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(deleted) < 1) )  
 AND 3 IN (SELECT userid FROM subscriber_table AS S WHERE S.userid='3') AND A.id > 01
```